# python3 decode byte string encoded in base64

Tags: python, utf-8, base64, decode

I know how to decode a base64 string and decode a UTF-8 string. The string I have has some other type of problem.

I have a web app sending a parameter value as a URL encoded Base64 encoded *someting* encoded string which I'm struggling to decode to string.

Here's the orignal value `I8PhvhSPMM23ie9C0mNJoA%3D%3D`
Removed URL encoding it look like normal base64  `I8PhvhSPMM23ie9C0mNJoA==`

When I try and decode it, I get struck. Normal base64 decoding looks like this

```
>>> _string = "I8PhvhSPMM23ie9C0mNJoA=="
>>> _decoded = base64.b64decode(_string)
>>> _decoded
b'#\xc3\xe1\xbe\x14\x8f0\xcd\xb7\x89\xefB\xd2cI\xa0'
```

When I run this decoded byte string through .decode() I get the below. I tried UTF-8 and Latin-1.

```
>>> print(_decoded.decode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
>>> print(_decoded.decode('latin-1'))
#Ãá¾0Í·ïBÒcI 
>>>
```

I'm trying to decode the value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't base64-encoded binary data?

Comment: I'm not sure. The original string comes through to the backend as a parameter value

Comment: [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) doesn't recognize any text encoding with this.  It's likely binary data.  Why encode *any* text in base64? base64 "textualizes" binary data.  Text is already text.

Comment: How can I process this as binary data to see what it is?

Comment: Binary data isn't usually self-documenting. For a complete file, dedicated tools (like Unix `file`) might be able to guess what it is based on magic bytes in the beginning, but for a single parameter value this won't work. You'll need to find the specs in the documentation of the web app.